# How do I open kernel from grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I had installed Linux mint 20 on my 64x 32gb Dell laptop but I decided to switch to Ubuntu so I installed UNetbootin and tried to install Ubuntu 20 but after the installing and everything I rebooted and  it came up with GNU GRUB version 2.04 and UNetbootin is the only option. I press enter and get

```
error: disk `hd-2,0' not found. 
error: you need to load the kernel first. 
Press any key to continue...
```

I looked it up and saw a few things but they don't seem to be working.
The only thing with files on it is (lvm/vgmint-root) and the basic efi/ and grub/ is on a different partition or drive. I've tried

```
set root=(lvm/vgmint-root)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic
```

But the rest of that process leads to kernal panic after I try to boot

Comment: Ok how would I do that?

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu has both *yy* release and *yy.mm* format releases, they are different products and should not be confused. You mention Ubuntu 20, which to me implies Ubuntu Core 20, a *snap* only release where a desktop can be installed, it however runs completely as a *snap*.  All Desktop & Server releases (which can use *deb* files) however are *year.month* in format, eg. Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS.   Ubuntu 20 is unclear, and implies a different product.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, i had this problem the other day to. You need to reinstall your thing. You can not open kernel from there. So i'd suggest not having to put up with this because you'll waste less time by reinstalling the operating system (i mean deleting the files and putting it onto another or the same USB)